# I lost the Node.js debug button in chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, debugging

The button for nodejs debug is lost :c

Before it was:

[image]

After:

[image]

Where is the button?

P.S. node app is running and displayed in chrome://inspect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems to be a Chrome issue. Chrome 66 (current 'stable') seems to be broken, but not the upcoming Chrome 67 or the 68.

Wait for 67 stable..

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20590

Answer (score 0):

You can also open `chrome://inspect` in google chrome to access the debugging console.